# RestResource being Triggered upon Viewing a Record

Tags: apex, restresource

Overview - i recently was assigned to take over a project which was started by an outside consultant. I am unfamiliar with RestResources which is what this project was built on. MY ISSUE:**I need to get this deployed but want to ensure i am not missing any components which are necessary for it to function.** Currently i pretty much only know i need this class and the custom setting created.

This project is essentially doing an auto-deduplication function on cases created via inbound emails within a certain time frame based on having the same subject line (including the RE:'s from replies within that time frame)

The code i modified was in this class (posted below) and i was able to get the desired result, i just am unsure what else is triggering the code to run when the record is viewed.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/find_duplicate_cases')
global without sharing class akaFindDuplicateCasesREST{
    public static final String DUPLICATE_STATUS = 'Closed/Duplicate';
    public static final String RESOLUTION_NOTES = 'Closed Automatically - system identified this case as a duplicate; refer to Parent Case';



    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost(String recordId) {
        if (isCaseId(recordId)) {
            Id caseId = Id.valueOf(recordId);
            List<Case> originalCase = [
                    SELECT Id, 
                            MS_Current_Department__c, 
                            MS_Source_Queue__c,
                            Subject,
                            CreatedDate
                    FROM Case
                    WHERE Id = :caseId
                    AND MS_Source_Queue__c != NULL
                    AND Subject != NULL
            ];
            //add if custom setting checkbox = false or program != best buy or red wing, do nothing
            String parsedSubject = '%' + originalCase[0].Subject.toLowerCase().replace('re: ', '').replace('fwd: ', '').replace('fw: ', '');
            if (originalCase.isEmpty() == false && originalCase[0].MS_Current_Department__c != 'Financial Controls') {
                Datetime startingTime = originalCase[0].CreatedDate.addMinutes(-1 * akaDuplicateCaseHandlerSettingMgr.MINUTES_BEFORE_CREATEDDATE);
                Datetime endingTime = originalCase[0].CreatedDate.addMinutes(akaDuplicateCaseHandlerSettingMgr.MINUTES_AFTER_CREATEDDATE);


                List<Case> duplicateCases = [
                        SELECT Id
                        FROM Case
                        WHERE CreatedDate >= :startingTime
                        AND CreatedDate <= :endingTime
                        AND Subject like :parsedSubject
                        //AND MS_Source_Queue__c != :originalCase[0].MS_Source_Queue__c
                        AND Id!=:originalCase[0].Id
                        AND Status = 'New' order by CreatedDate desc
                ];

                set<Id> duplicateCasesIdSet = new set<Id>();
                for(Case case0 : duplicateCases) {
                    duplicateCasesIdSet.add(case0.id);
                }

                if(duplicateCases.isEmpty() == false){
                    List<Account> duplicateCaseAccounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id=:akaDuplicateCaseHandlerSettingMgr.DUPLICATE_CASE_ACCOUNT_ID];
                    List<Contact> caseOriginatorContacts = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id=:akaDuplicateCaseHandlerSettingMgr.CASE_ORIGINATOR_CONTACT_ID];
                    Account dupCaseAcct = duplicateCaseAccounts.isEmpty() == false ? duplicateCaseAccounts[0] : null;
                    Contact caseOriginatorCont = caseOriginatorContacts.isEmpty() == false ? caseOriginatorContacts[0] : null;

                    updateDuplicateCases(originalCase[0], duplicateCases, dupCaseAcct, caseOriginatorCont);
                }
                list<EmailMessage> emailMessagesToInsert = new list<EmailMessage>();
                set<Id> emailMessageIdSet = new set<Id>();
                boolean findAttachments = false;
                for(EmailMessage em : [select id, Subject, FromAddress, ToAddress, HtmlBody, TextBody, HasAttachment from EmailMessage where ParentId IN: duplicateCasesIdSet]) {
                    emailMessageIdSet.add(em.id);
                    if(em.HasAttachment) {
                        system.debug('Here findAttachments = true');
                        findAttachments = true;
                        //set boolean to query and clone attachments/reparent
                    }
                    EmailMessage em0 = new EmailMessage();
                    em0.ParentId = duplicateCases[0].id;
                    em0.Subject = em.Subject;
                    em0.HtmlBody = em.HtmlBody;
                    em0.TextBody = em.TextBody;
                    em0.FromAddress = em.FromAddress;
                    em0.ToAddress = em.ToAddress;
                    emailMessagesToInsert.add(em0);
                }
                if(emailMessagesToInsert.isempty() == false) {
                    insert emailMessagestoInsert;
                }


                List<Attachment> attachmentList = new list<Attachment>();

                if(findAttachments) {
                    system.debug('Here2 - findAttachments = true');
                    for(Attachment attach : [SELECT Id, body, ContentType, Name FROM Attachment WHERE parentId IN: emailMessageIdSet]) {
                        Attachment newAttach = attach.clone();
                        newAttach.ParentId = originalCase[0].id;
                        attachmentList.add(newAttach);
                    }

                }
                if(attachmentList.isEmpty() == false) {
                   insert attachmentList; 
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @TestVisible
    private static void updateDuplicateCases(Case originalCase, List<Case> duplicateCases, Account duplicateCaseAccount, Contact caseOriginatorContact){
        if(originalCase != null && originalCase.Id != null && duplicateCases != null && duplicateCases.isEmpty() == false) {
            for (Case duplicateCase : duplicateCases) {
                duplicateCase.ParentId = originalCase.Id;
                duplicateCase.Status = DUPLICATE_STATUS;
                duplicateCase.MS_Resolution_Notes__c = RESOLUTION_NOTES;
                if(duplicateCaseAccount != null){
                    duplicateCase.AccountId = duplicateCaseAccount.Id;
                }
                if(caseOriginatorContact != null){
                    duplicateCase.ContactId = caseOriginatorContact.Id;
                }
            }

            Database.update(duplicateCases);

        }


    }


    @TestVisible
    private static Boolean isCaseId(String strId) {
        Boolean valToReturn = false;
        try {
            Id parsedId = Id.valueOf(strId);
            valToReturn = parsedId != null && parsedId.getSobjectType() == Case.getSObjectType();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            valToReturn = false;
        }


        return valToReturn;
    }




}
```

Comment: Hi - can you try to limit the code sample a bit, or speak out more of your concerns? The community will be able to answer you better

Comment: Code does not run when a record is viewed inside a standard page. We’re missing valuable context here.

Comment: Realistically, there's no real way to find out without checking documentation (hopefully your organization has some?!). It could be called from a Visualforce page, a button, some other website, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no documentation provided from the consultant on this new feature. I have been looking through the audit trail and i have seen a couple other classes that have been modified/created around the same time. I can add those above in my question but it will be pretty lengthy.

Comment: Update - i believe it is being triggered by an email service that i just found. I am unfamiliar with these so i will begin additional research now.

Comment: Just as an update - it was being called via an 'invisible' lightning component which would trigger the code whenever someone first opens and views a case. I only found the component by hovering over the entire page in the lightning app builder, trying to find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was being called via an 'invisible' lightning component which would trigger the code whenever someone first opens and views a case. I only found the component by hovering over the entire page in the lightning app builder